# edit already present button upon being pressed

Tags: button, discord.js

I have a simple Discord Bot setup, that automatically sends embeds with a button into newly created Tickets (first part) and then picks up the button press and sends a conformation (second part), which is also supposed to then update the button to be both deactivated and have a different label.

How would I go about this? All other questions/guides had the embed sent using a prior interaction and therefore could use its attributes.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => { //Sends the Embed with Button upon Tank Ticket Creation
    if (message.author.id === '149565760950239232' && message.channel.name.includes('ticket')) {     
        
        const tanksEmbed = new EmbedBuilder() //The Embed sent on Ticket Creation
        .setColor(0xb054c8)
        .setTitle('First steps to get your tank souls:')
        .setDescription('Press the button below to submit your order.')
        .setFooter({ text: 'Contact Aldoraz#0001 for issues and questions' })
       
       const tanksButton = new ActionRowBuilder() //The button on the Embed
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('tanks_button')
                .setLabel('Submit Tank Order')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                .setEmoji('')
                .setDisabled(false),
        );

        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [tanksEmbed],
            components: [tanksButton]
        });
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => { // Sends Conformation on Button press and Updates Button
    if (!interaction.isButton() && !interaction.customId === 'tanks_button') return;
    console.log('Button pressed!');
    let channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === interaction.channelId);  
    interaction.reply('Button was pressed!')  

    const tanksButtonClicked = new ActionRowBuilder() //The updated button on the Embed
        .addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('tanks_button_pressed')
                .setLabel('Order Submitted!')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                .setEmoji('')
                .setDisabled(true),
        );
    interaction.message.edit({components: tanksButtonClicked})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `client.on("interactionCreate")`, that's for slash commands.

What you need to do in order to collect the button is create a `collector` on the message, and updating the button once it's pressed.
You can also create the `collector` on the channel, but doing it on the message is preferred.

Add `async` to your client event:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {})
```

Store your message in a variable:

```
const MSG = await message.channel.send({embeds: [tanksEmbed], components: [tanksButton]});
```

Create your `filter` and `collector`

```
const filter = i => !i.user.bot;
const collector = MSG.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 20000 });
```

Then, if the button is pressed, send the form and modify the button.

```
collector.on(`collect`, async i => {

  // here we check if someone else used the button
  if(i.member.id != message.author.id) {
    return i.reply({ content: `${i.member} This button is not for you`, ephemeral: true})
  }

  if(i.customId === 'tanks_button') {

    // Your code that does its thing.

    tanksButton.components[0].setLabel('Your new Label').setDisabled(true);
    MSG.edit({embeds: [tankEmbed], components: [tanksButton]});
  }
})
```